# Map Mannually Created Table as M2M in Django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have table T1 (list of all words Used in Text) and T2 (list of Text).

I have created another Table T3 with foreign key to T1, and T2 so that it can act as M2M, in T3. I additionally add another column called WordCount, so i cannot create this table with models.ManyToMany Field! Can I access T2 from T1 using Many to many Constrains in Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `"through"` attribute in your many to many model:

Here's a simple example I got from this link:

https://gist.github.com/jacobian/827937

You can find more about it here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

In this case the example has a person with a many to many rel to groups. But we need some additional fields on the relation, so we create a Through Model called Group Member. Notice that the intemediate model GroupMember has a foreign key to both Person and Group, and some other fields that you might need.

Django's ORM takes care of the constraints when you write the models like this.

```
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', through='GroupMember', related_name='people')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='membership')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='membership')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s is in group %s (as %s)" % (self.person, self.group, self.type)
```